# How can I contribute to the scientific community using my telescope?

Tags: amateur-observing, fundamental-astronomy

I've been using my Meade 90 ETX for a few years trying to become a better astronomer and am familiar enough with the basics to navigate my way around. I was wondering in what way an amateur astronomer such as myself can contribute to the scientific community. I would like to try and do more than just stargaze and take pictures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amateurs do useful scientific work by being many-handed and widely spread.

Many Supernovae are discovered by amateurs. You need a set-up that can image one galaxy after another and look for any "new stars" that appear in them. As you are looking for the appearance of a Mag-14 star you need a big mirror; 90mm might not be enough. However look to [Backyard observatory supernova search](http://www.bosssupernova.com/) for more information. With the right equipment, you might find 1 SN every 5000 galaxies imaged.

You can also contribute by observing asteroid occultations. These occur when an asteroid passes in front of a star, blocking out its light. By timing the occultation you can get an idea of the size of the asteroid in one cross-section. If multiple people observe the same occultation from different locations you can get a picture of the shape of the asteroid. See the [Asteroid occultation site](http://www.asteroidoccultation.com/) which links to FAQs and a page for submitting reports.

Answer (score 6):

You can also help the study of variable stars and in particular their light curves - You do not require a big scope for this. See for example the [American Association of Variable Star Observers](https://www.aavso.org/), or the [British Astronomical Association Variable Star Section](http://www.britastro.org/vss/).